# Mylyn commit default message missing

Tags: eclipse, git, github, task, mylyn

I'm using EGit with mylyn. When I used to commit my code to git repository, the commit dialog would be filled by default message showing the task ID, task description, etc.

Now I don't see the default commit message any more.

I looked it up online and people suggest that EGit Mylyn plugin need to be installed, and I do have that plugin installed.

Comment: What platform you running on?  I'm having the same issue and none of the suggestions have helped.  I wonder if it is because I'm using a shared Linux installation where eclipse is installed by root in a read-only directory.  I have had issues with other plugins because of this.

Comment: Did you already find a solution? I also have the problem that after switching between tasks, the commit-message is not changed. It only works after restarting eclipse,...

Comment: I'm having this issue in Eclipse Mars despite having all the plugins installed. Possibly because I have per-project commit templates. A workaround is to select the project in Project explorer and hit `Ctrl`+`#` to open the commit dialog, and then click the "Open Git Staging view" link in the bottom right. That will insert the correct template into the commit message.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a useful value at *Preferences -> Mylyn -> Team -> Commit Comment Template* and is the checkbox "Automatically manage (change set) with task context" directly above that message checked?

Comment: Hi Thanks for pointing that out. It turns out I don't have the "Team" tab under Mylyn. That can be the issue. Do you know which plugin I should install?

Comment: It's in the plugin org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui. That might be in the feature "Mylyn Task-focused interface".

Answer (score 0):

The commit message will only show up when you try to check in at least one file that has been changed while the task in question is active and you have this task active (the blue ball).

This behavior has been changed in one of the last releases (3.7 ?), before it was sufficient to just have the task active.

Comment: Thanks. I have the task activated, and also have changes to commit. But the message wouldn't show up. I'm familiar with the basic workflow since I've been using it all the time. I suspect some particular eclipse plugin got screwed up which causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Team options under *Preferences -> Mylyn*, you need to install the Mylyn task focussed interface from http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest

Once done, set something sensible for the *Commit Comment Template*.  I use

```
${connector.task.prefix} ${task.key}:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a fresh Eclipse 2021-12 installation after adding the Mylyn connector for our bug tracker.

The issue was a missing plugin, I did:

- Help -> Install new software
- Select the relevant version under "Work With"
- Under "Collaboration" select "Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface"
- Install the plugin

Strangely this happens with the "Java" edition of Eclipse but not with the "Enterprise" edition where the plugin is bundled by default